# Kotlin: runBlocking to make asynchronous call synchronous gets ignored

Tags: android, kotlin

Im new in kotlin and have to extract some heavy data from server before anything.
That's why i need a synchronous function
So... i made this:

- Function:

```
private fun fnCargaCatalogos() : Boolean{
        mPermisosAlmacenes = ObjPermisoAlmacen()

        try {
                runBlocking() {
                    async {
                        commonModel.cargaPermisosAlmacenes(user,1)
                        commonModel.obtenPermisosAlmacenes().observe(owner, Observer { response ->
                            if (response != null) {
                                if (response.permiso?.tienePermiso == true) {
                                    mPermisosAlmacenes = response
                                    almacenesAdapter = ArrayAdapter(
                                        applicationContext,
                                        R.layout.spinner_item,
                                        mPermisosAlmacenes.contenido
                                    )
                                    spWarehouses_origen.adapter = almacenesAdapter
                                    spWarehouses_destino.adapter = almacenesAdapter

                                    // Asignando valor default si hay uno
                                    if (response.permiso?.valorDefault != 0) {
                                        for (i in 0 until almacenesAdapter.count) {
                                            if (almacenesAdapter.getItem(i)!!.nCodAlmInterno == response.permiso?.valorDefault) {
                                                spWarehouses_origen.setSelection(i)
                                                break
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    runOnUiThread { tools.showMessageDialog(
                                        owner,
                                        "Error",
                                        "No tiene establecido los permisos de Almacenes"
                                    )}
                                    mPermisosAlmacenes = ObjPermisoAlmacen()
                                }
                            } else {
                                runOnUiThread{tools.showMessageDialog(
                                    owner,
                                    "Error",
                                    "No se encontro el catálogo de almacenes"
                                )}
                                mPermisosAlmacenes = ObjPermisoAlmacen()
                            }
                        })
                    }.await()
                }

                if (mPermisosAlmacenes.permiso == null){
                    runOnUiThread{tools.showMessageDialog(owner, "Error", "Error cargando datos de almacenes")}
                    return false
                }

            return true
        } catch (e: java.lang.Exception){
            tools.showMessageDialog(
                owner,
                "Error",
                "Ocurrio un error al configurar los catalogos:" + System.lineSeparator() + "<<${e.message.toString()}>>"
            )
            Log.e("CARGA_CATALOGOS", "Error: " + e.message);
            return false
        }
    }
```

- Model:

```
fun cargaPermisosAlmacenes(cLogin: String, nPermiso: Int) { mPermisosAlmacenes = cloudRepository.cargaPermisosAlmacenes(cLogin, nPermiso)}
    fun obtenPermisosAlmacenes() = mPermisosAlmacenes
```

- Repository:

```
fun cargaPermisosAlmacenes(cLogin: String, nPermiso: Int): MutableLiveData<ObjPermisoAlmacen>{
        var mResponse = MutableLiveData<ObjPermisoAlmacen>()

        cloudApi.cargaPermisosAlmacenes(cLogin, nPermiso).enqueue(object: Callback<ObjPermisoAlmacen>{
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<ObjPermisoAlmacen>, response: Response<ObjPermisoAlmacen>) {
                Log.e("PERMISOS_ALM_RESPONSE", "ResultCode: " + response.code());
                Log.e("PERMISOS_ALM_RESPONSE", "" + Gson().toJson(response.body()));
                //if (response.isSuccessful) mResponse.value = response.body()  else mResponse.value = null
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    mResponse.value = response.body()
                }  else {
                    mResponse.value = null
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ObjPermisoAlmacen>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.e("PERMISOS_ALM_ERROR", ""+t.cause?.message);
                Log.e("PERMISOS_ALM_ERROR", ""+t.message);
                mResponse.value = null
            }

        })
        return mResponse
    }
```

- Expected:
  1.- run obtenPermisosAlmacenes
  2.- get mPermisosAlmacenes
- What it happens:
  1.- obtenPermisosAlmacenes ignored and directly check mPermisosAlmacenes

What i'm supposed to do to run obtenPermisosAlmacenes parallel checking if mPermisosAlmacenes catch some info?

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your code to look like

```
mPermisosAlmacenes = runBlocking {
   commonModel.cargaPermisosAlmacenes(...)
   ...
   } else {
     ...
     ObjPermisoAlmacen()
   }
}
```

There is no need for `async` or `await` or assigning to the variable inside the `async` block.  (I suspect assigning to the variable, instead of returning its new value, is your real issue.)

Comment: Thanks, but it does the same, returns null.
My function does get values, i know because i see them at debug, the problem is that runblocking gets skipped instead of waiting for a value for mPermisosAlmacenes

Comment: Ah.  Using `observe` just leaves a callback without actually waiting for it.  You may have to use whatever framework you're using (Rx?) to ensure that that callback actually happens.  Alternately, you could write `val mPermisosAlmacenes = CompletableDeferred()`, assign to it by writing `mPermisosAlmacenes.complete(value)`, and make sure you wait until it's assigned to (and get its value) by writing `mPermisosAlmacenes.await()`.